# How to remove the last item in jinja nested loop?

Tags: python, jinja2

With a single loop, it's easy to write `{% if not loop.last %}JOIN{% endif %}` to remove `JOIN` from the last iteration of the loop.

With nested loop, we can [access the outer loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/#accessing-the-parent-loop), allowing us to check if we're in the final iterations of both loops.

Still, I have a 3-level nested, for which this solution is quite verbose:

```
{% set loop1 = loop %}
...
{% set loop2 = loop %}
...
{% if not loop1.last and loop2.last and loop.last %}JOIN{% endif %}
```

Is there a better way to skip the last iteration of a nested loop?

Comment: Given the facilities provided by Jinja2 I do think this is the best way.

Comment: @blhsing you can take a look at my answer for various ways to use Jinja2 facilities to make this less verbose.

Comment: To be 100% correct, in the "best-way-chosen" question example, the "and" conditions have to be surrounded by round brackets, thus: "{% if not (loop1.last and loop2.last and loop.last) %}" - otherwise it will give wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to write a little Python, you can make it a clean one liner by writing a custom filter (this code has to run before you load any templates) or just adding `all` to your global Jinja2 environment:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape, last

env = Environment(
    loader = PackageLoader('yourapplication', 'templates'),
    autoescape = select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
)

def between(token, *args):
    return token if all(x.last for x in args) else ''

env.globals['between'] = between
env.globals['all'] = all
```

Now you can do:

```
{{ 'JOIN'|between(loop1, loop2, loop) }}
# or
{% if not all([loop1, loop2, loop]|map('last')) %}JOIN{% endif %}
```

Otherwise, you can implement a Jinja2 [macro](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#macros) that uses the special `varargs` variable to access all unnamed arguments passed to the macro as a Jinja2 list.

```
{% macro between(token) -%}
    {% if not varargs|map('last')|select|length == varargs|length -%}
        {{ token }}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Note that the use of `-` in the example indicates that whitespace before `{%-` and after `-%}` will be removed when the macro expands. Now the usage:

```
{{ between(token = JOIN, loop1, loop2, loop) }}
```

You can keep an assortment of Jinja2 utility macros in a file and include it at the top of your templates like so: `{% include 'util.jinja2' as 'util' %}` and the usage becomes:

```
{{ util.between(token = JOIN, loop1, loop2, loop) }}
```

An alternative to making a macro collection and using it in your templates is to do it inline in your templates. Here's an idea for a one liner to do the trick:

```
{% set loops = [loop1, loop2, loop] %}
{% if not loops|map('last')|select|length == loops|length %}JOIN{% endif %}
```

Comment: I ended up just using the verbose solution to make sure that my code is readable to colleague. I'm accepting this answer as another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, expanding the common set of knowledge by adding your own macros is challenging for a team environment. Jinja2 makes that easier by allowing you to use custom filters, instead. Once you see the use case for a dozen filters or so, you can agree upon them as a team, and since it's Python code instead of macro expansions, it's easy to understand in the team environment.